Is there a way to disassemble a polyline with curves so that I can check angles between each of the tangents?
I am new to AutoCAD plugin programming and C#. I'm trying to place points along a polyline in C# for a function I am writing, and I need to know when the point is being placed, is it on a curved portion, and what is the angle between the tangent lines on either end of the curved portion. A single polyline might have multiple curves, but will always have tangents between them.
My current function, without the additional functionality, takes a polyline input from modelspace and uses GetPointAtDist to calculate points along the polyline at set intervals. I'm not really sure where to start to get that additional info I need. I thought maybe I could build lines and curves along the polyline so that I could assign each segment/curve a variable but that seems inefficient.

You can get tangency vector then You can get angles between vectors
Point3d p0 = axis.GetPointAtDist(d0);
Vector3d v0 = axis.GetFirstDerivative(p0);    
Point3d px = axis.GetPointAtDist(curentDist);    
Vector3d v = axis.GetFirstDerivative(px);    
double angle = v.GetAngleTo(v0);


Ok this makes sense. My current logic is just building all the points one at a time, but I actually need to be keeping track of the last point to make a comparison. I don't even need to keep track of the polyline because the vectors on the tangent sections will be equal.

@MickSullivan If You find this response useful upvote or accept the answer so I can get reputation points. Here on StackOverflow we like reputation and we are more likely to response to You in future if You appreciate us.

To get the components of a Polyline, use  Polyline.GetGeCurve(), this will return a CompositeCurve3d (AcGeCompositeCurve3d), which is a container of component curves that are connected end-to-end.
